# Открыть страницу в новом окне браузера

Tags: html

Моя кнопка:

```
<input type="button" name='save_as' value="Сохранить как" onclick="window.open('save_as.php','_blank')">
```

Не смотря на то, что есть `_blank` страница `save_as.php` открывается в новой вкладке, а не в новом окне. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка и как всё-таки заставить открываться страницу в новом окне браузера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. С точки зрения javascript окно браузера и вкладка - суть одно и то же.

Решает, где ему удобнее открывать страницы - пользователь.

В браузере Chrome всегда открываются новые вкладки, это когда-то была основная "фишка" браузера.

В Firefox по умолчанию открываются вкладки - но это настраивается на основной странице настроек:

[image: скриншот]

В IE по умолчанию открываются новые окна, но это тоже настраивается:

[image: скриншот]
[image: скриншот]

---

Если же вам *очень* надо открыть именно новое окно - можете использовать вызов `open` с указанием параметров в третьем аргументе. Но лучше так не делайте.

Comment: В общем, благодаря вашему комментарию про третий аргумент, я задала ширину и высоту открываемого окна и получила то, что хотела. Спасибо. =)