# Открыть ссылку в новом ОКНЕ браузера

Tags: javascript

*Реализую виджет "поделиться".*

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Использовал для атрибута `a` `target="_blank"`, но открывает в новой **вкладке**, а нужно в новом **окне** браузера.

Пытался через `window.open();` Но всё равно открывает в новой вкладке.

Хотя, допустим, если перейти на другие сайты и нажать на "поделиться в вк", то откроет ссылку в новом **окне**, как реализовать подобное через vanilla js?

*P.S. [аналоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589375/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5) не помогают.*

*P.S.S. и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568283/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) тоже не ясно, ведь на других сайтах это реализуется.*

Answer (score 0):

Добавь метод, который будет создавать новое окно заданных размеров с твоей ссылкой

```
function setOnclick(a) {
a.setAttribute("onclick","popupWin = window.open(this.href,'contacts','location,width=1300px,top=0,left=100px'); popupWin.focus(); return false")
}
```

после вызывай этот метод `setOnclick(имя кнопки/ссылки)`
Было бы хорошо видеть как у тебя это реализовано =)